# Shutting down MongoDB inside Docker container causes 100% CPU

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, odroid

I've been pulling my hair over this one for days now, to the point I am dropping this here. Using docker-compose I start a few containers, one of which is running mongodb, using CMD ["/usr/bin/mongod"] However, when I shut down the container using docker stop, the mongod process takes 100% cpu and keeps running forever without being able to kill it. When killing the parent processes, the mongod process becomes a child of init, but in its same state. Mongodb does log that it shutted down with error code 0 though.

Docker version: 17.04.0-ce
Docker-compose version: 1.11.2

What I tried so far:

- different linux distro's
- supervisord within container to handle mongod
- added --init to docker daemon
- run mongod as a fork
- look for kernel update, but 3.14 seems to be the latest (running on Odroid C2)
- different storage drivers, but only aufs works (overlay needs higher kernel)

All without any joy..

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/71? One person talks about disabling the jounral storage

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the kernel to 4.x on the Odroid-C2 using [this link](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=135&t=22717&sid=27440adc5c50f4174f85fa694e36759e&start=250), the problem went away.